# How to preserve grouping in subquery

Tags: mysql

Hello i have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total, 
    COUNT(referrer) AS referrer,  
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y") AS YEAR, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") AS MONTH, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d") AS DAY
FROM 
    users
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)
ORDER BY 
    created_at ASC
```

This gives me table with totals sorted by day (month and year). what i need is to add a subquery to display one more count() which has a condition. Something like:

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE result = '1') as winners
```

the problem obviously is with the grouping of main query since i get same result without grouping the subquery for every row.

What would be the right way to execute such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total, 
    COUNT(referrer) AS referrer,  
    SUM(case when result = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as winners
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y") AS YEAR, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") AS MONTH, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d") AS DAY
FROM 
    users
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)
ORDER BY 
    created_at ASC;
```

Assuming `created_at` is a timestamp, we could re-write your query with just one field to group by as follows:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total, 
    COUNT(referrer) AS referrer,  
    SUM(case when result = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as winners
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y") AS YEAR, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") AS MONTH, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d") AS DAY
FROM 
    users
GROUP BY date(created_at)
ORDER BY 
    created_at ASC;
```

Please note I do not have `mysql` to hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both queries with `UNION`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total, 
    COUNT(referrer) AS referrer,  
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y") AS YEAR, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") AS MONTH, 
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d") AS DAY
FROM 
    users
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)
ORDER BY 
    created_at ASC
UNION
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at), 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)
HAVING result = '1'
```

Comment: this might work, but im going with Sashikanth Dareddy sa it is more readable. thnx